# Load jar using bytearray, cant find nested classes

Tags: java, jar, classloader

### Idea

I have a jar (`postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar`) in a `byte[]`. Id like to load and connect and run some basic SQL commands in runtime.

### Implementation

Therefore I created a new Classloader:

```
public class JarClassloader extends ClassLoader {

    public interface DriverProblemReporter {
        void reportDriverProblem(String name, Throwable e);
    }

    private final byte[] driverdata;

    private final DriverProblemReporter problemReporter;

    public JarClassloader(byte[] jar, String drivername, DriverProblemReporter reporter) {
        super(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        this.problemReporter = reporter;

        try {
            JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(jar));
            JarEntry entry = jis.getNextJarEntry();
            while (entry != null) {
                handleEntry(entry, jis);
                entry = jis.getNextJarEntry();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.driverdata = jar;
    }

    private void handleEntry(JarEntry entry, JarInputStream jis) {
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
            try {
                baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                IOUtils.copy(jis, baos);
                baos.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                problemReporter.reportDriverProblem(entry.getName(), e);
                return;
            }
            try {
                defineClass(baos.toByteArray(), 0, baos.size());
            } catch (LinkageError e) {
                problemReporter.reportDriverProblem(entry.getName(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Jar loads successfully and I am able to get a instance of the Driver.

### Point of interrest

On the call to connect to a Database I get this Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/hostchooser/HostRequirement$1
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:107)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:406)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:274)
```

In the stacktrace I see the working instance of `org.postgresql.Driver` looking for a class named `org/postgresql/hostchooser/HostRequirement$1`.

### Assumption

My `JarClassloader` does not load anonymous nested classes.

### Question

What shall I do to successfully load all classes in the jar?

Comment: Why is your jar in a byte array?  Where did that byte array come from?  If it came from a file, you should not be loading it into a byte array;  you should be passing the URL of the file to a URLClassLoader.

Comment: @VGR It does not come from a file. I could write a servlet, but the application-server(tomcat) does not have a http-connector to serve http-requests. I also could write a url-protocol-handler, but this might bring security doubts.

Comment: I would use [Files.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)(null, ".jar"), then [Files.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)(tempFile, driverdata), then `new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { tempFile.toUri().toURL() })`.  In other words, write the bytes to a temporary .jar file, and make a standard ClassLoader from that file.

Comment: @VGR A temporary file can be changed or might not be allowed to created because of disk full or invalid rights and might keep space after kill of the process. Also by design it caches the single-source-of-truth into a file-based cache. Technically the jar-file is the source-of-truth, by design the byte-array is the source-of-truth. Single-source-of-truth requires to have the technical and design soure-of-truth are the same.

Comment: Your reasoning could be applied to all use of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the classes in the order the classloader needs them, not in the order they happen to be in the JAR file. So you need to override the `findClass()` method and search the JAR file at that point for the class being requested.

It would be a lot simpler to use a file.